# Does the 'Sneaky' augment affect the sound of Phantom's cloak and datacores?

Tags: dirty-bomb

[image]

I've heard many "Yes it does" to "No it doesn't" from many Phantom players, and I'd like to clarify what this augment does.

As far as I know, Sneaky is supposed to minimize the amount of sound you make while running, aka, footsteps. However, it's known there are other running sounds that make noise, like Phantom's cloak, as well as running with a Data Core.

So I'd like to clarify my question: does Sneaky only affect running footsteps or does it also affect the cloak sound and the datacore sound?